# Store dropdown as live variable?

Tags: php, jquery

I've got the following PHP:

```
<?php
$default = 'Select a job role';
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT Job_Title FROM rates";

$result = mysql_query($query);

while($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$action = $myrow['Job_Title'];
echo "<option value='$action'".($action == $default ? ' selected="selected"' : '').">$action</option>\n";
}       
?>
```

I need to store whatever they select from this dropdown as a variable.  Obviously if they change their choice it will keep changing the variable.

The reason behind this is I have another select statement whose results depend on the selection here. 
If it can't be done with just PHP then Jquery is the preference if needed.

```
<select name="job-role">
<option value="J1">J1</option>
<option value="J2">J2</option>
<option value="J3">J3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Please post the rendered markup, we cannot render your php codes.

Comment: jquery would be the way to go, what have u tried?

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [*red box*](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update the value in the variable when a new value is selected, use the jQuery [`.change`](http://api.jquery.com/change) event handler. As for communicating this new value to the server, you can do this using [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/). I include an example [post request](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) below.

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    var jobRole = $('select[name="job-role"]').val();

    $('select[name="job-role"]').change( function() {
        jobRole = $(this).val();
    });

    //...
    $.post("url.php", "jobRole="+ encodeUriComponent(jobRole), function() {
        // success
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change a php variable based on a dropdown, unless you post the form back to the page itself or sends it via AJAX. If you want to fetch the value using jquery you can do something like

```
$(function(){

    var selectValue = $('select[name="job-role"]').val();

    $.post('somepage.php', { valueToSend: selectedValue },function(data){
        //HTTP-post completed
    });        

});
```

**somepage.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['valueToSend'])) {

    $selectedValue = $_POST['valueToSend'];

    //use $selectedValue in your query 
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  So if I wanted to throw this back into a PHP statement such as $query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = variable"; How would I go about that?

Answer (score 0):

try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/54p8y/2/) jsfiddle.

```
$(function(){
var selectValue = $('select[name="job-role"]').val(); //gets default selection
//alert(selectValue);
$('select[name="job-role"]').change(function(){
selectValue = $(this).val(); //gets changed selection
//alert(selectValue);
});
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it via php unless you do what Johan suggest. In jQuery, you need to bind the change method to your `select`

```
var value = '';
$('select[name="job-role"]').change(function() {
    value = $(this).val();
})
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ZCP5d/)